ESRI Land Cover 2050 download
I need a 2050 land cover map for Central and South Americas. I found ESRI's 2050 Land Cover raster but was not able to download it.
They have an online interactive map, but with no download option. I found two links that mention downloading (this and this), but the downloaded file is blank. I even created a trial account for ArcGIS online, but nothing changed.
I tried importing it to QGIS, but it says:

Connection failure: error 499.

Am I doing something wrong or is the file just not available to the public?

To load an imageserver service like https://env1.arcgis.com/arcgis/rest/services/Land_Cover_Projection_2050/ImageServer
Use QGIS 3.36+

To export as an image right click the layer and export - you will need to choose and provide the correct dimensions (pixel sizes) to export with the correct projection. (geotiff worked well).
